# What kind of plug adapter do I need?

Tags: receptacle, cord-and-plug

See the image below. This is from a lamp. Clearly it needs some kind of adapter to go into an outlet (I assume it came with one many years ago). Any idea what the name is of the kind of adapter I need? And do I need to pay attention to voltage, watts, etc when making the purchase?

[image][image]

Here's the label that sits right under the lamp. It reads `50W Smaller 12V Type T Bulb`, with various markings underneath it.

[image][image]

And finally, here's the lamp itself.

[image]

Comment: Let us see the other end of that, and a close up of the light bulb or lamp it is connected to.

Answer (score 5):

It's very likely to be a proprietary connector. Even if it conforms to a standard size like DIN (as @Trout suggests), that doesn't really tell you anything about the electrical requirements. The part your missing may have a transformer, a dimmer, or allowed ganging of several lights together.

Unless you find more markings on the bulb or cable, I would not assume anything about the lamp — could be DC or AC, could be 220V, 110V, or low voltage.

(You don't say what country you live in or whether the lamp is likely to be foreign. There are several countries that use plugs with 3 round pins in approximately the configuration of your plug, but yours looks smaller. It's a little hard to tell scale from that photo... any chance of pin-to pin-measurements?)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. I have updated my post with more pictures, including the voltage (12V) and another view of the pins. They are only 2-3mm apart.

Answer (score 4):

Max,

Looks like a Din connector.  I'd look for it on Mouser or Grainger.  Maybe even McMaster.

Check out the lamp itself because I'd bet that the light source is low voltage.    This is the kind of connector typically used for low voltage.  I suspect that the transformer the lamp came with is misplaced.  If this is the case, its easy to discover the needs of the source and replace the transformer.

I definitely would check the light source voltage before wiring in a regular ( Edison ) connector and plugging it in.   Of course, the pyrotechnics would be lively!

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, looks like a low-voltage connector.   If you can find info on the bulb type, it'll give you a clue as to the voltage and whether it requires AC or DC.

Comment: I updated my post with more images, including the bulb info (50W Smaller 12V Type T Bulb). I took a look on the websites you recommended but I have to admit that I'm still pretty lost. Am I looking for a transformer with a female Din connector on one end and a normal plug on the other?

Comment: Where do you live?   Mail it to me.  I'll repair this lamp for $995.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to find the power supply and connector pre-made to fit a weird old lamp connector is a needle-in-haystack problem, and not likely to be one with a satisfying result. But there's no need to approach it that way.

Simplest approach:

Get a 12V X 4.2-5.0 (or greater, but not less) Amp power supply (50W @ 12V = 4.167A)

Chop off the plug.

Use a multimeter to assess where each plug wire goes (probably ground to the case, and each side of the bulb) and connect up to the power supply to suit - or connect to one side of a NEW 3-terminal connector pair and connect the other side to the power supply.

Enjoy.

Comment: Know of any good tutorials on how to do this? I have no experience with this sort of thing.